# webpage to be get displayed perfectly in different browsers

Tags: java, jsp

In an interview , regarding java , interviewer asks many question on core java then he asks mainly the frameworks like spring ,struts but later he ask one question let say there is a web page and he has a project containing many jsp pages but the issues is that when he hit the url of his website in firefox browser the site get opened perfectly but when he hit the url on internet explorer the web page alignment is disturbed , it is not displayed perfectly and similiar problems was observe in other browser too, so which settings he need to perform in order to webpage get reflected perfectly in all browser, Please advise for this.

Comment: Cross-browser compatibility is a pretty complex issue, and unfortunately not a simple matter of "performing some settings". Also, it's the produced HTML/CSS/etc that matters; whether you use JSP or something else on server-side is irrelevant.

Comment: Javascript is a big issue here too.

Comment: @jonik Thanks but he expects the answer in sort of a general way, I yhink css and html settings to be perfect for all the browsers

Comment: I would check for the user's browser and serve up a different css file. To the end user it looks "perfect" but is in fact a chunck of if statements.

Answer (score 0):

As many commenters have noted, there is no one right way to do it. I would take a look at conditional comments. They render as commented out code in normal browsers, but in IE get picked up as directives to allow additional formatting.

Take a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

from the above reference:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

And you can do lot of tricks with these to explicitly set properties that IE renders differently/mysteriously/auto-magically

One important one is

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
```

which will allow you to set a property for any version less than or equal to IE9 (much better than having conditional statements for each and every version your client may want to render)